# How to use an array in switch statements?

Tags: arrays, switch-statement, tcl

Is it allowed to use an array element using tcl switch statement? I have an array named

```
set name "pad"
set p_list("pad") "IO2"
```

and now trying to do some conditional based stuff on that array like

```
 % switch $p_list($net_name) {
      IO1 {
           puts "io1"
      }
      IO2 {
         puts "io2"
      }
      default {
         puts "default"
      }
    }
```

but it seems array can't be passed to switch and therefore, erroring out with following error
can't read "pads_list(pad)": no such element in array

Could someone please suggest if it's allowed or not. If, allowed then how can I make it work?

Comment: Your array element is `"pad"`, not `pad`...

Answer (score 1):

Double quotes are not special in Tcl when not at the start or end of a word. Tcl is not Python or C. This means that you've made an array element with the name `"pad"`, *including the double quotes.* That's legal, but quite unusual in the sort of application you're writing. (The `switch` you've written looks absolutely fine.) Either you should write:

```
set p_list(pad) "IO2"
```

or:

```
set net_name "\"pad\""
```

I'm guessing that the former is the one you want.

Possibly also:

```
set p_list($net_name) "IO2"
```

And you can change around variable names too.

---

There are some other options too:

```
set "p_list(pad)" "IO2"
```

```
set net_name {"pad"}
```

I don't think these are likely to make you happy, but they'll do the right thing.

Comment: I'd also recommend cleaner indenting, but it doesn't really matter for small examples. In larger programs, clean indenting helps to make it easy to read code quickly.